# Ionizing with 980nm laser

Tags: laser, ionization-energy, laser-interaction

I have been looking at a 980 nm, 5-250 mw, 1 Hz to 1000 kHz pulsed IR laser. I understand that it takes 13.6 eV to ionize oxygen, and 15.6 eV to ionize nitrogen. Our pulses are only every 1,000,000 femtoseconds, but that is still ridiculously fast (0.000,000,001 seconds).

So the first question is how many milliwatts do I truly need if it is only 15.6 eV to ionize nitrogen. Also, will the 980 nm wavelength be a problem for targeting nitrogen? Finally I would like to use a focal lens where F=20 cm, but I'm not sure if it will still ionize. I am willing to get any focal lens for it to ionize even if it is right in front of the lens.

Also I've been talking to my chemistry teacher and he says its not really called ionization, as ionization totally removes the electron from the atom, rather its called the "quantum leap". I just want to know if he is right and if he is which is easier to do to produce light. I did a lot more research this time around and am ready to help clarify if I wasn't specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the process im trying to complete is called photoionization. Second, a $980\,nm$ laser wont work because if you take 1240/eV of element your trying to ionize = wavelength (nm) required. For nitrogen which is 15.58 eV that is $~80\,nm$. So no, if your doing a single photon process you need 80nm, but you can do a miltiphoton ionization process which you can increase the wavelength (in nm) and still get out the same Energy (in eV). In the single photon process power (in mW) does not matter, only in the aspect that the dot of light would be more visible, but wouldn't change if it ionizes or not.